# Automation script won't work if no one is connected to a Windows VPS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vps, rdp, automation, session

I have a automation script (mouse and keyboard automation) which works with a application installed on a Windows Server 2012 VPS.

It works perfectly when I am connected to the VPS via RDP. But when I am not connect, the script won't work! It stops/freezes, this is very strange. I guess that it needs a virtual display/screen/session to work properly. I have searched about this but none of the solutions worked for me, so as a last hope I am posting it here.

The script does some automation task when called from PHP (It is not a PHP script, PHP just calls the script) and returns some information back after automating. This won't work when I am not connected to the VPS so it returns a `502 Gateway Timeout` error. The automation script seems to stop at the point where it's supposed to focus/click something...

Comment: Can you post the script and how do you call it?

Comment: Hi @duenni, the script is an AutoIt script and I cannot post the script because of NDA. The script is called by PHP. More technical details can be found in this question at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841450/uiautomation-wont-work-in-a-vps-if-i-am-not-connected-via-rdp

Comment: I have managed to find a workaround, anyone interested may find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746816/3815591).